# Efficient way to get average string in list

Tags: java

Having a List that could contain an undefined number of "A", "B", "C" or "D", I have to calculate the average letter in the list.

For example, having [A, C] the average is B.

This is my approach:

```
public static String calculateAverage(final List<String> letters) {

    int numberOfA = 0;
    int numberOfB = 0;
    int numberOfC = 0;
    int numberOfD = 0;
    for (String letter : letters) {
        if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            numberOfA++;
        }
        if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            numberOfB++;
        }
        if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            numberOfC++;
        }
        numberOfD++;
    }

    int average =
        (numberOfA * 1 + numberOfB * 2
            + numberOfC * 3 + numberOfD * 4)
            / letters.size();

    if (average>=1 && average<2) return "A";
    if (average>=2 && average<3) return "B";
    if (average>=3 && average<4) return "C";
    return "D";
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What is an average letter ? if the list contains `[A, C]` is the answer `B` or undefined?

Comment: `[A, D]` is also `B` but is that what you want?

Comment: what about `[Ax3, Bx2, Cx4, Dx1]` what is the average then?

Comment: It's dangerous to go alone. Take this ascii table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: `if (average>=1 && average<2)` ... what value, except from 1, do you expect to "allow" here? If it is only "1", then use `if (average==1)` or a `switch`.

Comment: What is the average of [%,$]?

Comment: @Raedwald The average is: not even close of the defined range of "A" to "D". ;D

Comment: @cozyconemotel either B or C, both are fine

Comment: who down voted and why? Since you don't know the answer, you cannot down vote it. The questioner already implemented the code and want to know if it efficient or not. If you downvote it atleast care explain why you did so.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab I haven't voted on this question, but *"Since you don't know the answer, you cannot down vote it."* is obviously incorrect. One doesn't need to know the answer to vote according to the quality of the question. Why the voters think that the question is bad, is a different question.

Comment: I agree it may not be the reason, but assumption will be they don't know the answer ;) if they down-vote it without citing a reason . But without a reason down voting discourages people to ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

If they are single characters, just sum them and divide by the count:

```
char averageCharacter(List<String> cs) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (String c : cs) {
    sum += c.charAt(0);
  }
  return (char) (sum / cs.size());  // Potentially with different rounding.
}
```

You might want to round the integer division differently:

- Floor is just `sum / cs.size()`
- Ceil is `(sum + cs.size() - 1) / cs.size()`
- Round is `(sum + cs.size() / 2) / cs.size()`

Answer (score 0):

First: 
You have an error in your code:
`numberOfD++;` is always called, because you don't use an `if` clause.

My approach would be (without writing it, this looks like a Homework you should do yourself):

Assign a int for A-D (lets say 65-68, what would be their char value)...

- Loop through your String, add the value of the current Character to an counter
- Afterwards divide the counter by the number of characters in your string
- Result would be the ascii value of the "avarage" character, which you can cast to char.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have validated your input (ie, all entries in the list are a valid 1-character letter):

```
int count = 0;
int total;
for(String s : letters) {
    total += (int) s.charAt(0);
    count++;
}

int average = total / count; //Watch out here, this is integer division.

//convert back to char:
return (char) average;
```

Comment: Cast to `int` isn't necessary, nor is `count` really.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code is incorrect. You are incrementing `numberOfD` each time, no matter what the letter is. At least make this correction:

```
        for (String letter : letters) {
        if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            numberOfA++;
        } else if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            numberOfB++;
        } else if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            numberOfC++;
        } else 
            numberOfD++;
    }
```

How about just averaging the unicode values:

```
    char[] letters = {'A','B','C','D'};
    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : letters) {
        sum += (int)c;
    }
    System.out.println((char)(sum/letters.length));
```